# Severity level on docker logging to syslog

Tags: docker, logging, syslog-ng

I have a [syslog-ng](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng) container that collects logs from other containers running on the same application, and normal logging works as intended: every container send its logs and syslog-ng saves them on separate files, as defined in `syslog-ng.conf`.

I'm also trying to save error logs on a different file. I was assuming that everything thrown to STDERR from inside another container should be seen by syslog-ng as an error, so when I started a container like this:

```
docker run -dit --log-driver syslog --log-opt syslog-address=tcp://my_syslog:601 alpine echo "boom" > /dev/stderr
```

then I expected syslog-ng to understand it to be an error, but it does not.

This is an extract of my `syslog-ng.conf` inside the syslog-ng container:

```
@version: 3.25
source s_net {
  network(transport(tcp) port(601));
  network(transport(udp) port(514));
};
destination d_error_file {
  file("/tmp/errors");
};
filter f_errors {
  level(err .. emerg);
};
log {
  source(s_net);
  filter(f_errors);
  destination(d_error_file);
};
```

How can I tell syslog-ng to treat STDERR messages as errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original reply to set up a `/dev/stderr` source was misinformed. I thought that `syslog-ng` was running in the host.

As `syslog-ng` is running in the container, the docker daemon is collecting the logs from the running container and sending it over the network to the syslog server.

This is why the filtering has to be performed on the network source which is just as you have done.

I setup the following project to demonstrate an example.

```
.
├── data
│   └── syslog-ng
│       ├── conf
│       │   └── syslog-ng.conf
│       └── logs
│           ├── errors
│           └── syslog
├── docker-compose.yml
└── hack.sh
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  hack:
    image: alpine
    command: /hack.sh
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://host.docker.internal:601"
    depends_on:
      - syslog
    volumes:
      - '$PWD/hack.sh:/hack.sh'
  syslog:
    container_name: syslog-ng
    image: balabit/syslog-ng:latest
    volumes:
      - '$PWD/data/syslog-ng/conf/syslog-ng.conf:/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf'
      - '$PWD/data/syslog-ng/logs:/var/log'
    ports:
      - 514:514
      - 601:601
```

**hack.sh**: A shell script that logs to stderr and stdout

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
    echo "boom" >/dev/stderr;
    echo "no boom";
    sleep 2;
done
```

**./data/syslog-ng/conf/syslog-ng.conf**: filter `info` to `/var/log/syslog` and `error` to `/var/log/error`

```
@version: 3.29
@include "scl.conf"

source s_net {
   udp(
     ip("0.0.0.0")
   );

  network(
    ip("0.0.0.0")
    transport(tcp) 
    port(601)
  );

 };
  
  filter f_errors {
    level(err .. emerg);
  };
  filter f_info {
    level(info);
  };

    destination d_file {
      file("/var/log/syslog");
    };
    destination d_error_file {
      file("/var/log/errors");
    };

      log {
        source(s_net);
        filter(f_info);
        destination(d_file); 
      };
      log {
        source(s_net);
        filter(f_errors);
        destination(d_error_file);
      };
```

Other than creating a different filter for non-error messages, there is little difference between the above `syslog-ng` configuration and the one you have provided.

Comment: I've tested your example with my `docker run` above, but it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried different combinations, but nothing goes into the error file. If you have an example (Dockerfile for syslog-ng and syslog-ng.conf) that works with my `docker run` line, can you please post it?

Comment: @AlessandroCappello Your log filter appears set up the right way.

Comment: It works! I will check further to see what's wrong in my configuration, but I could quickly see that yours works just great. Thank you very much for your help!